# Swift set camera permissions manually

Tags: ios, swift, camera

I'm using a card scan library that has a boolean method call to check if the camera permissions have been set. Is there a way in Swift 3 that I can manually set the permissions based on an alert action controller.

I don't want to to create another imagepicker if one is already been created via the library.

Can this be done?

Thanks

Comment: No, you cannot change permissions that were defined with system alert

Comment: Permissions can only be set by the official Apple Alerts. You can't use your own alert to update the permission. What you can do however, is if you detect the setting is turned off, is prompt the user with an alert to open the app settings and change the permission. This alert can directly open the app settings. See here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationopensettingsurlstring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can not do that. But of course you can let user to grant permission with following code and then you can store the value in a bool variable for future use.

```
if AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(forMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) ==  AVAuthorizationStatus.authorized
{
   // Already Authorized
}
else
{
   AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(forMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, completionHandler: { (granted :Bool) -> Void in
      if granted == true
      {
         // User Granted
      }
      else
      {
         // User Rejected
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: @EricAya Edited my answer with swift code. Hope that will help :)

Answer (score 1):

**No.**

For security reasons, there is no way to set the app permissions programmatically, as this can easily cause manipulative behaviours in potentially malicious apps. Apple also wants to develop a streamlined interface for crucial security settings, including permissions for individual apps.

Comment: Ok, I am using the same alertController as the camera permissions. A dummy ImagePicker it is :)